# Difference between input: [] and @Input()

Tags: angular

I have just started to dabble in the whole child and parent component communication side of things in Angular 4 and I have noticed some older videos use the syntax `input: []` rather than the more commonly seen `@Input()` syntax, is there any difference between the two? And if not, is there a preference?

Comment: Weird, ive never seen that. You have any links/examples?

Comment: @diopside I think I mis-understood the usage, all is clear to me now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean two different things:

- `@Input()` decorator that specifies that a certain property is passed to the current component from the parent component (I.e. `@Input() highlightColor: string`) - [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding)
- `input: []` component property named `input` and of type `Array` - [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Notice that `@Input() input: []` is perfectly valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

@Input() is used when you pass some value from a parent component to the component itself.

The input:[] is a normal property with the name input